# Will serviceProvider.GetService<T>() with Singleton registration generate unique class everytime?

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am registering my classes in Asp.Net Core services like this:

```
services.AddTransient<WebSocketConnectionManager>();
services.AddSingleton(ChatHandler);
```

And then I am using that classes like this:

```
app.Map("/chat", (_app) => _app.UseMiddleware<WebSocketManagerMiddleware>(serviceProvider.GetService<ChatHandler>()));
```

In this case, and as a chat app (will receive multi WebSockets connections on that "/chat" path), and each one as I understand will need its own ChatHandler.

Will the line -I am using- create a unique ChatHandler class for each connection? if yes, then what does Singleton here mean? (because it will not be singleton anymore).

If not is it write to have this scenario in chat application? (one handler will handle everything?). I maybe misunderstand something..

Comment: Just because `WebSocketConnectionManager` isn't a singleton doesn't mean that `ChatHandler` isn't still one.

Comment: @DavidG Actually I am asking about `ChatHandler` with `serviceProvider.GetService`, will I get unique `ChatHandler` everytime I use `serviceProvider.GetService`?

Comment: i know what you're asking, but because you are using the DI system to get the `ChatHandler` object, it's still a singleton.

Comment: So I will never get a second copy as long as I am using the DI system? that is what I thought, but because it is a chat app, it didn't make sense to me that only one ChatHandler will handle all connections. Thank you.